# How can I wait for a window to close and than perform any operation in QTP?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to perform a operation after a window is closed, i.e Suppose I have a window or any dialog popped up and now I want my code to wait until this particular dialog get closed and after that I want to code continue.

Means I want to wait till that window is opened without using hardcoded 'Wait()' function.

Is there any method in VBScript or QTP that fulfills my needs?

Comment: `Status` property. Provides status information about a script run with the `Exec()` method. The `Status` property returns a value from an enumerated type:
`WshRunning` ( = 0) The job is still running.
`WshFinished` ( = 1) The job has completed.

Comment: Can you elaborate with example? I mean suppose a dialog is opened over a java window and I want to wait till dialog get closed.How can I perform it in QTP over that dialog's hierarchy? Eg: Dialog("xy") is added in OR of QTP. Now I want to wait till this Dialog exists.So How can I do so ?

Comment: In pure vbscript:
`
    Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"):  
    Dim oExec: Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("calc"):  
    Do While oExec.Status = 0:  
        WScript.Sleep 100:  
    Loop:  
    WScript.Echo oExec.Status  
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the 'WaitProperty' method on your window to determine when visible property becomes false, but that might throw an error once the window is no longer available.  Otherwise, you can always loop until it no longer exists

```
While Window("My Window").Exist(0)
    Wait 0, 500 ' Pause briefly before looking again
Wend
```